# Issue Tracker for Open Atrium 2.0

Tags: distributions

I just installed Open Atrium 2.0 and noticed, as many people have, that the Issue Tracker functionality is not included. I understand why they didn't want to include it in version 2: to make way for a better solution that fits in with Drupal Core.

However, this functionality is pretty killer for what I use Open Atrium for.

So, other than https://drupal.org/project/oa_worktracker, are there other alternatives to implementing issue tracking within Open Atrium. I guess I'm unaware of a standard issue tracker for D7.

Comment: I am curious too, seems like it's needed IMO, I will post back if I find anything or testing the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know whats OA2 friendly but [Case Tracker](https://drupal.org/project/casetracker), and [Project Management](https://drupal.org/project/pm) are both D7 friendly.

From the project page of Case Tracker:

> Actually, the 7.x-1.x-dev version has the content types for Project
>   and Cases working without problems. The Notifications, Actions and
>   View integration that needs to be tested.
>
> The development is active and we're working toward a release. Check
>   out the 7.x-1.x branch and post your patches!

From the project page for Project Management:

> Project management software, allowing you to manage:
>
> Organizations, Teams, People, Projects, Tasks, Tickets, Timetrackings,
>   Notes, Invoices, and Expenses. Each of these features is managed as a
>   separate module within the suite.

Comment: I think I've seen those, but I'll have to check them out again. We actually started using JIRA, and the need went away.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is long after the OP presumably moved on, but for posterity...

I'm using an issue tracker on an OA2 system. I didn't set it up, but I'd be very surprised if what we used wasn't standard stuff.

OA2 in this case uses the 'Task' content type for issue tracking, which is implemented by `oa_worktracker`, which I can see in the filesystem at `.../htdocs/profiles/openatrium/modules/apps/oa_worktracker`.

http://docs.openatrium.com/node/294 also shows the Tracker as part of OpenAtrium.